# What, if anything, can be done with intelligent cross-aligned artifacts?

Tags: nethack

My neutral caveman found a Mitre of Holiness and an Orb of Detection in a bones pile.  I hate leaving good items, esp. artifacts, just laying around. Aside from burying them, or letting a pet have them, is there anything I can do with them?  Helm of Opposite Alignment excluded--can't wear both helms and already have Orb of Detection (as well as +18 bought protection).  I do have wand of Polymorph if they can polypile.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you've not yet identified a helm of brilliance yet, take this opportunity to `N`ame it from the `f`loor.
2. About your polypile idea:  While the Book, Bell, Candle, and Amulet of Yendor, can't be [polypiled](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Polypiling#Probability_of_item_loss_and_golem_generation_for_wand_and_spell).  All other artifacts have (only?) a 95% chance of resisting each polymorph attempt.  Good luck.
3. Alternatively, spare Quest Artifacts might make fine bait for Rodney's [Covetous](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Covetous) attack, but I'm not sure I'd carry around another heavy crystal ball for such a small benefit.

Personally, I'm not sure I'd be too concerned about an inability to wear the [Mitre of Holiness](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/The_Mitre_of_Holiness).

- You probably already have intrinsic Fire Resistance, as it's not tough to get.
- The 1/2 damage from undead & demons is only available to Priests anyway.
- As the game's 2nd worst spell caster, a caveman would probably need a robe more than a helm of brilliance to become a decent caster.  In any case you can still use a normal helm of brilliance if you *really* want to go that route, and Rodney won't be undressing you in combat.
- Instant 1/2 Mana recovery on Invocation:  How much mana is your caveman going to be spending anyway?
- If you need the [+1 MC](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Magic_cancellation), you can be get that from a ring (or better, cloak) of protection (that Rodney won't steal).

Let's be honest, for a caveman, the +1 MC is probably the most compelling aspect of that artifact.  Given your high intrinsic protection, a +0 ring of protection should do the job without adding to the rate at which you [burn nutrition](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Nutrition#Losing_nutrition).

Another fine choice of headgear for a melee character that just might want to cast some spells is the Elven Helm.  No spell casting penalty and can be enchanted for better protection than a helm of brilliance.